# Mapfish Print Grid Layer

Tags: mapfish, mapfish-print

I am using Mapfish Print 3 to print map with grid layers. The printing Engine is working fine.[image: Map with grid]

I want to label grid value in **Degree Minutes Seconds Format**

Example: **40° 26′ 46″ N** or **79° 58′ 56″ W.**
How to do that?. can any one help?

Request JSON(http://localhost:8080/print/print/crosses_point_grid/report.png)

Documentation: http://mapfish.github.io/mapfish-print-doc/layers.html#Grid%20Layer

```
{
    "attributes": {
        "map": {
            "bbox": [
                66.687007759,
                34.5660284950001,
                74.894126892,
                38.491359711
            ],
            "dpi": 254,
            "layers": [
                {
                    "font": {
                        "name": [
                            "Liberation Sans",
                            "Helvetica",
                            "Nimbus Sans L",
                            "Liberation Sans",
                            "FreeSans",
                            "Sans-serif"
                        ],
                        "size": 8,
                        "style": "BOLD"
                    },
                    "gridType": "points",
                    "haloColor": "#CCFFCC",
                    "haloRadius": 4,
                    "indent": 10,
                    "labelColor": "black",
                    "labelFormat": "%1.0f %s",
                    "numberOfLines": [
                        5,
                        5
                    ],
                    "renderAsSvg": true,
                    "type": "grid"
                },
                {
                    "baseURL": "http://localhost:8020/geoserver/watershed/wms",
                    "opacity": 1,
                    "type": "WMS",
                    "layers": [
                        "watershed:mask_basin_and_watershed"
                    ],
                    "imageFormat": "image/png",
                    "styles": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "customParams": {
                        "CQL_FILTER": "gid=1 AND layer='basin'",
                        "TRANSPARENT": true,
                        "TILED": true,
                        "EXCEPTIONS": "application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage",
                        "scaleMethod": "accurate",
                        "access_token": "None"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "baseURL": "http://localhost:8020/geoserver/watershed/wms",
                    "opacity": 1,
                    "type": "WMS",
                    "layers": [
                        "watershed:Slope"
                    ],
                    "imageFormat": "image/png",
                    "styles": [
                        ""
                    ],
                    "customParams": {
                        "TRANSPARENT": true,
                        "TILED": true,
                        "EXCEPTIONS": "application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage",
                        "scaleMethod": "accurate",
                        "access_token": "None"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "longitudeFirst": true,
            "projection": "EPSG:4326",
            "rotation": 0
        }
    },
    "layout": "A4 landscape"
}
```